# Getting value from listbox in another class

Tags: c#, class, variables, listbox

I'm triying to get the value of the selected item in a listbox which is in another class from the one from I'm trying to get the data.

What I do is the following:

Calling class:

```
Form1 form = new Form1();

var mail = form.getMail();
var pass = form.getPass();
```

Main class:

```
public string getMail() {

    return this.listBoxMail.SelectedValue.ToString();
}

public string getPass()
{
    return this.tb_pass.Text;
}
```

Always getting NullReferenceException. **I ALREADY KNOW** what this error means, what I need is to solve it. Any idea about how to achieve this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you get this error? Which **reference** is `null`?

Comment: listBoxMail.selectedValue is null

Comment: Are you sure listBoxMail is null and not `listBoxMail.SelectedValue` ??

Comment: I'm sure listBoxMail.SelectedValue has a value

Comment: If you claim listBoxMail is null there is no way listBoxMail.SelectedValue even exists. Please debug and answer my question above.

Comment: `listBoxMail` wouldn't be null. Just check it using **breakpoint** that what is actually null

Comment: After I execute "var mail = form.getMail();" I get "A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in FIFA.exe"